# Existence of (nearly) number of digits preserving pairing function?

Tags: functions

A pairing function $\pi$ is a bijective mapping $ℕ×ℕ → ℕ$. That means it can reversibly encode two integers $a$ and $b$ into one integer $p$.

The most well known pairing function is the Cantor pairing function:

$$\pi(a, b) = \frac{1}{2}(a + b)(a + b + 1) + b$$

The pairing functions that I know usually bloat $a$ and $b$ so that the number of digits of the result is often much higher than the number of digits of $a$ and $b$. Does a pairing function exist which (nearly) preserves the number of digits? I.e.

does a pairing function $\pi$ exist which fulfils, with $p = \pi(a, b)$:

$$d(p) < d(a) + d(b) + c$$

where $d(n)$ is the number of digits required to represent an integer $n$ and $c$ is some constant?

Comment: How many pairs of 27-digit numbers are there? So, how long must the numbers be, to represent them all?

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: Are you still here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary is a little neater than decimal, so let's do it that way. It shouldn't be hard to work out the analogous results for decimal.

The number of pairs $(a,b)$ of nonnegative integers with $d(a)+d(b)\le n$ is $n2^{n-1}$, where $d(x)$ is the number of bits it takes to write $x$ in binary. For example, take $n=3$, then we are talking about the $3\times2^2=12$ pairs $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(10,0),(10,1),(11,0),(11,1),(0,10),(0,11),(1,10),(1,11)$.

The number of nonnegative integers $c$ with $d(c)\le m$ is $2^m$. So if we are going to encode every pair $(a,b)$ with $d(a)+d(b)\le n$ with a number $c$ with $d(c)\le m$, then we need $2^m\ge n2^{n-1}$. Taking logarithms to the base 2, this is $$m\ge n-1+\log_2n$$ Since $\log_2n$ is unbounded, we can't achieve $d(p)<d(a)+d(b)+c$ for a constant $c$.

Comment: Nice proof. A bit confusing with the m and n maybe. Anyways, note that it could be disputed that (n/2 + 1) * 2^n is the number of pairs of integers with d(a)+d(b)<=n (with d(x) being the number of bits required for an integer x). This is because in binary format, the number 0 is often seen as requiring no bit. This is different in decimal format where by convention, the number 0 has one digit: 0.